# Cannot override prepareForSegue function

Tags: swift

import AVFoundation
import UIKit

```
class RecordSoundsViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var recordingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopRecordingButton: UIButton!

    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func recordAudio(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        print("The record button was pressed!")
        recordingLabel.text = "Recording in Progress"
        stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = true
        recordButton.isEnabled = false

        let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,.userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let recordingName = "recordedVoice.wav"
        let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
        let filePath = NSURL.fileURL(withPathComponents: pathArray)
        print(filePath)

        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)

        try! audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: filePath!, settings: [:])
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
        audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
        audioRecorder.record()
    }

    @IBAction func stopRecording(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        print("Recording was stopped")
        recordingLabel.text = "Tap to Record"
        recordButton.isEnabled = true;
        stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = false
        audioRecorder.stop()
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try! audioSession.setActive(false)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "stopRecording") {
            let playSoundsVC = segue.destination as! PlaySoundsViewController
            let recordedAudioURL = sender as! NSURL
            playSoundsVC.recordedAudioURL = recordedAudioURL
        }
    }

    func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
        print("\n Av audio recorder has finished \n")
        if flag{
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "stopRecording", sender: audioRecorder.url)
        }else{
            print("Saving the audio file was unsucessfull")
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to override prepareForSegue function it throws an error mentioning the superclass does not have overridden method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift 3 the signature of the method is

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

A way to figure out yourself is to comment out the entire method and retype the first few characters (`prep`). Code completion will help you.